# Extract filename.tar.gz / filename.tar.Z file using Java code by calling 7-zip exe on windows

Tags: java, 7zip

> Error from java code : Cannot use absolute pathnames for this command
>           Command failed with code 7

I am not able to extract filename.tar.gz file using java code which is calling 7-zip exe with its command line option.

while running 7z.exe from command prompt with same command provided in java code does the work.

Running from Command prompt :
`C:\Users\anil\Desktop\TestExtract> **C:\7-Zip\7z.exe x C:\Users\anil\Desktop\TestExtract\socket.tar.gz -so | C:\7-Zip\7z.exe x -si -ttar -oC:\Users\anil\Desktop\TestExtract\**

above thing works.

but providing above command through java code gives error :

```
public static String execute( String command )
{
    try
    {
        Process cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command );

        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(cmd.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");            

        // any output?
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(cmd.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

        // kick them off
        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

        cmd.waitFor();
        int exitVal = cmd.exitValue();
        return exitVal == 0 ? "OK" : "Command failed with code " + exitVal;
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Switches used here -so for redirecting to output stream and giving it to other command with pipe because{two step extraction to be done in single step without generating intermediate file}.

For handling stream used code is :

```
  import java.io.*;
  class StreamGobbler extends Thread
 {
    InputStream is;
    String type;

  StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type)
  {
    this.is = is;
    this.type = type;
  }

  public void run()
  {
        InputStreamReader isr=null;
        BufferedReader br=null;
       try
      {
        isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        br= new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line=null;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(type + ">" + line);   


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
      finally
      {
        try {
            isr.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `new StreamGobbler(cmd.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT")` is correct? Shouldn't it be `.getOutputStream()`?

Comment: What have you placed in your `String command` argument in your `execute` method ? (We would want to see that to check if e.g. you have gotten the escaping correct)

Comment: passing argument from eclipse as    "C:\\7-Zip\\7z.exe x C:\\Users\\anil\\Desktop\\TestExtract\\socket.tar.gz -so | C:\\7-Zip\\7z.exe x -si -ttar  -oC:\\Users\\anil\\Desktop\\TestExtract\\"

Comment: do your really need to use 7Zip? I would be easier to use the Java compression libraries.

Comment: yes beacuse i need to extract filename.tar and filename.tar.Z  file as well

Comment: `Runtime.exec` doesn't do pipes, you'd have to run the two 7z commands as separate processes and shuffle the output of one to the input of the other in Java. I suggest you look at Apache commons-compress, which can unpack tar archives in pure Java.

Comment: As Runtime.exec will run given command on command prompt internally or it execute command with parameter and it is executing 7z.exe which can understand pipe so the pipe is for 7z.exe as switch option  it doesn't have to do anything with java .  Runtime.exec execute given command with parameter.

Comment: Apache commons-compress doesn't support .tar.Z file so i have to go with 7zip  . can you suggest something [i don't want intermediate file generation ].I think Runtime.exec write command as it is to command prompt so it should have run above java code but it is not :-(

Comment: No, `Runtime.exec` doesn't understand pipes and it doesn't use `cmd.exe` to run anything unless you specifically tell it to (it just uses the native Windows CreateProcess API). The `-so` option to 7zip means "send output to stdout", the pipe is implemented by the command shell (when you run it from a command line) rather than interpreted by 7zip itself.

Comment: The latest commons-compress (1.9) _does_ support Z compression, you use `CompressorStreamFactory.createCompressorInputStream(...)` to auto-detect the compression format and return a suitable decompression stream, then create a `TarArchiveInputStream` from that.